# Attributes of model properties goes to view through view model - how to?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, attributes

How to bind the attributes of model properties to a view?

I have a model, for example:

```cs
class MyModel
{
    [Display(
        ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Strings),
        Name = "MyName",
        Description = "MyDescription")]
    public double MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And my view model is something like this (none unusual):

```cs
public class MyVM
{
    private Models.MyModel model;

    public string MyVMProperty
    {
        get { return model.MyProperty.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            // some usual code with parsing a value from textbox...
        }
    }
}
```

And in a view I want to bind the data from the attributes of model properties. Something like this:

```xml
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <TextBox 
        Text="{Binding Path=MyVMProperty}" 
        />

    <TextBlock 
        Text="{Binding Path=MyVM.model.MyProperty.DisplayAttribute.Name}" 
        />

    <TextBlock 
        Text="{Binding Path=MyVM.model.MyProperty.DisplayAttribute.Description}" 
        />
</Grid>
```

And somewhere in code I do:

```cs
myGrid.DataContext = new MyVM();
```

How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solution is to add helper class and pass the instance of that class as converter parameter. The instance must be initialized in XAML by hands. The instance consist of all the data required to obtain the value of the attribute of the property of the model instance. The solution is generalized and there are no hardcoded data inside of the converter logic. The "value" parameter of the converter is not required also.

So, the result looks like this:

Something in the same assembly as view model. Converter and helper class (simplified - without any null checks etc.):

```cs
namespace MyProject.Converters
{
    public class MetadataParameters
    {
        public Type ModelType { get; set; }
        public string ModelProperty { get; set; }
        public Type AttributeType { get; set; }
        public string AttributeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetadataConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var mp = parameter as MetadataParameters;
            var modelPropertyInfo = mp.ModelType.GetProperty(mp.ModelProperty);
            var attribute = modelPropertyInfo
                .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .Cast<Attribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault(memberInfo => memberInfo.GetType() == mp.AttributeType);
            var attributeProperty = attribute.GetType().GetProperty(mp.AttributeProperty);

            return attributeProperty.GetValue(attribute, null);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

In resource file (XAML):

```xml
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
...
<converters:MetadataConverter x:Key="metadataConverter" />
```

In view file:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"
xmlns:DataAnnotations="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;assembly=System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations"
xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:MyProject.Models"
...
<TextBlock 
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding
            Mode="OneWay"
            Converter="{StaticResource metadataConverter}">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <converters:MetadataParameters
                    ModelType="{x:Type Models:Model}"
                    ModelProperty="ModelProperty"
                    AttributeType="{x:Type DataAnnotations:DisplayAttribute}"
                    AttributeProperty="Name" />                            
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since attribute properties can only be retrieved using reflection, you will have to provide some means of converting a "(class OR object) + property name" tuple to something that exposes the values of these attributes.

A very specific solution would look like

```
public DisplayAttribute MyVMPropertyDisplayAttribute
{
    get
    {
        var prop = typeof(MyModels.Model).GetProperty("MyProperty");
        var attr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute));
        return attr.Cast<DisplayAttribute>().Single();
    }
}
```

and you could then bind to e.g. `MyVMPropertyDisplayAttribute.Name`.

Obviously this solution needs to be generalized so that it can be used conveniently across different model and attribute types; it would be a good idea to package it inside a value converter instead.

Comment: So you mean I must have an additional properties in my view model to represent the attribute's properties of model? Says I have two properties in model with two attributes for each. And each attribute has two properties for itself. And additional two properties in view model to represent properties of model. In result I have 2*2*2=8 additional properties and 2 properties by model in my view model, right? It is too much. Can it be done with another approach?

Comment: @user808128: Of course it's too much, which is why I said the solution needs to be generalized. There are two things that can be customized in the above getter: the name of the property and the type of the attribute (you might also need to pass the type of the model if you don't have it easily accessible). So for example an `IMultiValueConverter` that accepts three parameters could do this with configuration provided entirely from XAML. The mechanics would be the same as above.

Comment: IMultiValueConverter works with only one parameter (as well as IValueConverter), and its Object[] values must be binded to the properties of view model. So it leads to increase of properties count. I don't know how to elegantly cover it. It still requires one addition property for each model property. The simplest approach that I thinked up is to pass all the names (properties of model and properties of attributes of model) and (if required) data types into one converter parameter and then parse it inside the converter. It also looks not elegantly but less properties blowing.

Comment: And all of this looks like struggling with framework. Does it seems that I do something wrong or it is just framework that hasn't proper and elegant solution for this?

Comment: @user808128: `IMultiValueConverter` accepts a lot of values, so it doesn't matter there's only one parameter. The values will *not* be bound, there is no need to. You will just pass `typeof(Model)`, `"MyProperty"` and `typeof(DisplayAttribute)` (although of course in XAML that's `{x:Type ...}`).

Comment: Can you update your answer and paste a sample of code in XAML please? I have examined [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.convert(v=vs.100).aspx), and they use values through binding.

Comment: Well i received additional help from another source, and I combined it with your information. So the result solution works fine for me. And I didn't use the IMultiValueConverter - the IValueConverter was enough. I didn't even use the value parameter of IValueConverter converter.

Comment: @user808128: Glad to hear it worked for you. Passing in multiple pieces of information with a custom parameter class is very nice, although of course it does require an extra class. I do like the final solution.